# Unit xrdp.service could not be found

Tags: xrdp

Simple question but could not find any answer googling.

If I do

```
sudo systemctl status xrdp
```

and I got

```
Unit xrdp.service could not be found
```

Does this mean:

- xrdp is not installed?
- xrdp is installed but is not enabled?
- Another status?

And if it is the second one should I enable it with

```
sudo systemctl enable --now xrdp
```

or start it with

```
sudo systemctl start xrdp
```